# WCS GeoServer: Get subset of raster image

Tags: geoserver, wcs

I know that WCS is used to get the "raw" data of a coverage (such as an image), but is it possible to download only a subset of the image, for example a block of pixel 1000*1000 from the original image?

If not, is there a another GeoServer interface for that?

Comment: Of course, with standard WCS parameters which are rather different in different WCS versions. Usage is well documented in the standards.

Comment: I was trying to find it in the geoserver WCS but they don't say anything about a subset parameter, is there an example how to subset a WCS request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoServer provides a WCS Request builder under demos that allows you to construct and/or run WCS requests against your local server. WCS allows you to specify the subset that you require as a bounding box in map units as in this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><GetCoverage version="1.0.0" service="WCS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wcs" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wcs http://schemas.opengis.net/wcs/1.0.0/getCoverage.xsd">
  <sourceCoverage>nurc:mosaic</sourceCoverage>
  <domainSubset>
    <spatialSubset>
      <gml:Envelope srsName="EPSG:4326">
        <gml:pos>15.0 40.0</gml:pos>
        <gml:pos>17.0 41.0</gml:pos>
      </gml:Envelope>
      <gml:Grid dimension="2">
        <gml:limits>
          <gml:GridEnvelope>
            <gml:low>0 0</gml:low>
            <gml:high>34 24</gml:high>
          </gml:GridEnvelope>
        </gml:limits>
        <gml:axisName>x</gml:axisName>
        <gml:axisName>y</gml:axisName>
      </gml:Grid>
    </spatialSubset>
  </domainSubset>
  <output>
    <crs>EPSG:4326</crs>
    <format>GeoTIFF</format>
  </output>
</GetCoverage>
```

Comment: What does that example do? I guess <gml:Envelope> specifies the corners of the coverage you want to extract, but what does <gml:GridEnvelope> specify? Does Geoserver do on-the-fly rescaling (here to 34x24 pixels)?

Comment: Here's a link to more request builder info http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wcs/requestbuilder.html

Comment: And here are some examples http://mapserver.org/ogc/wcs_server.html

Comment: And here are some more examples https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/communicating-with-a-wcs-service-in-a-web-browser.htm

Answer (score 3):

WCS 2.0 support direct subset call from the url, example like below:

```
$wcs_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=GetCoverage&CoverageId=Canada:canada_clay_250_sl1&subset=Long('.$minX.','.$maxX.')&subset=Lat('.$minY.','.$maxY.')';
```

You can use Curl to download and store data locally. 
Same as WCS version 1.0, the two sets of coordinates are bottom left and top right. This will provide you are bounding box for data subset. 
Check OGC WCS2.0 document [here](https://portal.opengeospatial.org/modules/admin/license_agreement.php?suppressHeaders=0&access_license_id=3&target=http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/%3Fartifact_id=41439), subset section.

Comment: Note that `Lat` and `Long` may have different names, they must correspond to the `axisLabels` values of the `Envelope` field in the `DescribeCoverage` WCS request on the layer.

Comment: @MaxG Does the subset call extract the actual data or rescalled data like how bbox call does?
And is there anyway to do that in QGIS ?